# How to find the room in Which the socket is in?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I want to know the room in Which the socket is in ? I want to broadcast to the other sockets in the room during the disconnect event

Comment: I find it easiest to keep track of socket references myself, in a object or Map or something.  For example:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11356001/socket-io-private-message/11356019#11356019

Comment: Actually i am using another way now. I create an object which will store socket id as the key and room id as the value corresponding to the socket id. So when i need the room id i fetch it from the object

Comment: If you're only ever going to have a socket in one room at a time, you can just set that room as a property on the `socket` object when you join it to the room.  `socket.currentRoom = room`.  Then, upon disconnect, you can just access `socket.currentRoom` to see what room you had it in.

Comment: @jfriend00 yea this is a better method in comparison to my method of creating an object and setting its property/value . Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're only ever going to have a socket in one room at a time, you can just set that room as a property on the socket object when you join it to the room. `socket.currentRoom = room`. Then, upon disconnect, you can just access `socket.currentRoom` to see what room you had it in.

It is possible to dive into internal data structures to find out what rooms a socket is in, but if you're just using one room, then the `socket.currentRoom` is probably easiest.