# Socket.IO chat - "ping" specified client

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have simple Socket.IO based chat, and when User1 clicked on User2 at "friends list", User1 will be connected into room with User2 (based on "token" from server). Everything works without problem, when both have opened "chat window" (they are both in room).

But how can I "ping" the User2, when he have chat window closed (he isn't connected into room)?

Thank you for your help!

**EDIT:**

1. User1 opened his "Friends list" and select User2 (chat window opened - like FB)
2. Client JS request token for conversation User1 + User2
3. Node.JS side connect User1 into room with name = token

Okey, now is User1 in room. But User2 is not, because he is not opened window (but he is "online" = connected into server io.connect(...)).

1. User1 write some message and send it into room
2. Now I need to "ping" User2's client side JS and open chat window (get token, connect into room) with new message

Simplified client JS:

```
socket = io.connect "...", {port: 1234}
token = ajaxRequestToServerForToken mineID, hisID
socket.emit "joinIntoRoom", token
```

Simplified node.js code:

```
//In handler class
joinIntoRoom: (socket, token) ->
    socket.leave socket.room
    socket.join token

    socket.emit "connected"
```

Comment: It's not very clear what you mean here without a bit of code or pseudo code. Do you have a 'lobby' for connected users who are not in a room?

Comment: Ok, I added some more info. I have "lobby", when user connect to server, I save his socket like @clients[socket.id] = socket

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, you need a way identify user2 so you can emit an event to him.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913801/sending-message-to-specific-client-with-socket-io-and-empty-message-queue) has a similar answer - does it help?

Once you have a socket object for user2, you can just call 
`socket.emit('joinIntoRoom', {token: token, message: message})` with the first message, then the client should interpret that.

Comment: If I have a User2 socket ID, it's no problem to get his socket and emit some events, but where can User1 get User2 socket ID?

Comment: User1 doesn't need his id, the server does. When user 1 sends the first message to user2, the server should emit an event to user2 telling him to join room user1&user2. From then on, they can just send messages to the room.