# Avoiding Redis persistence (Socket.io + Cluster + RedisStore)

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, socket.io

I know that you can use [Redis for the communication between socket.io sockets from different cluster workers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647348/send-message-to-specific-client-with-socket-io-and-node-js) in node.js and also for sharing other objects between these workers.

But I'm struggling with the following:

Does the persistence of Redis data get in the way of this?
How can I be sure that the socket data is removed from redis when the master process is closed? And how can I ensure the same for the objects? I only need this data until the processes/sockets terminate.

Maybe I have to remove the save-to-disk interval and reload the whole Redis server on master-start?

Thanks so much.

Comment: If you're sure you don't need persistence for anything in your Redis instance, disabling it is the easiest way to go.

Comment: i understand, but the thing is that I'd like to have no information of the old sockets/objects sitting in the ram of the old node session when i restart node. is there any way to quickly clear everything from redis (or a group of sets)? or what would you recommend for that matter? would you recommend restarting it? thanks in advance :)

Comment: `FLUSHDB` will empty everything from the current Redis database, or `FLUSHALL` will delete everything from all databases.

Comment: @If that solved your problem, posted as answer you can accept.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `FLUSHDB` to delete all data from the current database or `FLUSHALL` to delete all data from all databases.