# socket io doesn't work both way?

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, real-time

My current problem is that there are two browsers (two users). Once both of them are connected, they could do a certain socket event which is a friends Request but not both at the same time. Always need to refresh one of the user's page.

Illustratively

[image]

When a user click this button

the navbar glyphicon will be incremented by 1

[image]

Serverside event

```
  io.on('connection', function(socket){
     // Everytime user is connected, I will do some Database operation to store the socketId, it will look something like this
     user.socketId = socket.id; // For simplicity.

     console.log(socket.request.user.username); // is using passport-socket.io library
     socket.on('friendsRequest', function(data) {
     // Got these two datas from input hidden on html by using Jquery
     var socketId = data.socketId;
     var userId = data.userId; 
     socket.to(socketId).emit('friendsRequest', socket.request.user);
     console.log("Successful" + " from " + socket.request.user.username);
});
```

The weird thing is , on the serverside it is always showing  `console.log("Successful" + " from " + socket.request.user.username);` meaning if click the button on both User's browser it will show correctly

```
"Successful from UserA" 

"Successful from UserB"
```

But the problem is on the clientside, the targeted html never changed, it always one of the browser navbar's glyphicon will be incremented

Here's the code on the client side

```
  // This event will send the targeted data like socketId and userId back to the server
    $(document).on('click', "#addFriend", function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var userId = $('#userId').val();
      var socketId = $('#socketId').val();
      socket.emit('friendsRequest', {
        userId: userId,
        socketId: socketId
      });
    });

    // Once the server has done doing his job, this event will listen.
    socket.on('friendsRequest', function(data) {
      var totalRequests = parseInt($('#totalRequests').html());
      console.log(totalRequests);
      totalRequests += 1;
      $('#totalRequests').html(totalRequests);
      $('#friendsRequested').append('<li>' + data + '</li>');
    });
```

The main problem is on the clientside `socket.on('friendsRequest');`

**It only works of one of the browsers but not both at the same time when I fired the friendsRequest event**

Need someone with socket.io expertise to explain to me why it doesn't work both ways. As to my logic it is supposed to work.

html

```
 <input type="hidden" name="socketId" id="socketId" value="ValueOftheSocketId" />
 <button type="submit" id="addFriend" class="btn btn-default">Add Friend</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the event 'friendsRequest' is not fired the error always will be when you emit it on server:

socket.to(socketId).emit('friendsRequest', socket.request.user);

It is probably that the socketId is not the correct, why? :

The socket.id is reset when a reconnection occurs. So that probably would cause that when you do: socket.to(socketId).emit('friendsRequest', socket.request.user);
it is sent anyone.

A reconnection can happen when a error occurs inside a event listener on client (it will not appear on console).

So for watch if that happens you can use the default event 'disconnect' on server:

```
 socket.on('disconnect', function () {
    console.log('user disconnected');

  });
```

Comment: I already implemented socket.on('disconnect') and I did save the socket.id in the User's database for later use. But when I refresh it's just won't work both way.

Comment: I believe this is a problem with reconnection?

Comment: I think is not good idea save the socket.id in db, when you refresh the socket will get a new id

Comment: I believe we need to chat.

Comment: So how do i retrieve the other User's socket.id if saving in the database is not a good idea?

Comment: i would need the full code to give you an exact answer

Comment: Gimme me one sec, I create a gist for this

Comment: Full code for , serverside https://gist.github.com/anonymous/faca6ad51263846bb613

Comment: Whats the news David?

Comment: What if I have thousands of users, don't you think for loop operation would be expensive run?

Comment: that must not be a problem

Comment: if you are worry about performance you could push the sockets.id in a array and use a normal "for loop" which is much faster than a "for in"

Comment: For avoid the loop maybe you can create a hash object where the key is the userId and the value is the socket.id, so you could get the socket id through userId, like: Hashobj[userId]

Comment: But if I use for loop, how exactly I am gonna get the other user's socket.id?

Comment: I stumbled upon this SO answer, they suggest to use room, but again how do i get the id. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17476294/how-to-send-a-message-to-a-particular-client-with-socket-io

Comment: I have another SO question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35044295/how-do-i-get-other-users-socket-id

Comment: Hope you could help me with this issue, Im feel like giving up already

Comment: In the example I wrote in gist the "s" is the id