# How do I get other users socket.id?

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

How do I get other user's socket.id?

Since socket.id is keep changing, whenever the browser refresh or disconnect then connect again.

For example this line of code will solve my problem

`socket.broadcast.to(id).emit('my message', msg);`

But the question is How do i get that id?

Let say Jack wants to send a message to Jonah

Jack would use the above code to send the message, but how to get Jonah's socket id?

Just for the record, I already implemented `socket.io` and `passport` library so that I could use session in `socket.io` , the library is call `passport-socket.io`. So to get the user id in socket.io would be

```
socket.request.user._id
```

Answer (score 5):

What i did for this was to maintain a database model(i was using mongoose) containing userId and socketId of connected users. You could even do this with a global array. From client side on socket connect, emit an event along with userId

```
socket.on('connect', function() {
    socket.emit('connected', userName); //userName is unique
})
```

On server side,

```
var Connect = require('mongoose').model('connect');; /* connect is mongoose model i used to store currently connected users info*/
socket.on('connected', function(user) { // add user data on connection
    var c=new Connect({
        socketId : socket.id,
        client : user
    })
    c.save(function (err, data) {
        if (err) console.log(err);
    });
})
socket.on('disconnect', function() { //remove user data from model when a socket disconnects
    Connect.findOne({socketId : socket.id}).remove().exec(); 
})
```

This way always have connected user info(currently used socketId) stored. Whenever you need to get a users current socketId fetch it as

```
Connect.findOne({client : userNameOfUserToFind}).exec(function(err,res) {
    if(res!=null)
        io.to(res.socketId).emit('my message', msg);
})
```

I used mongoose here but you could instead even use an array here and use filters to fetch socketId of a user from the array.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation suggests that `socket.on(SOME_MESSAGE's callback is provided an id as the fist param.

http://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/#default-room

`javascript
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('say to someone', function(id, msg){
    socket.broadcast.to(id).emit('my message', msg);
  });
});`

Comment: The id is from the client?

Comment: I'm pretty sure, and if not all sockets should have an id according to the docs http://socket.io/docs/server-api/#socket#id:string

Comment: I know that all sockets will have an id, but the question is how do i get other's user id? because socket.id will keep changing and its not good to use

Comment: ah sorry, namespaces could be of use; every client should be connected to root namespace by default, and then you could segregate clients into specific namespaces if necessary http://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/#namespaces