# socket.io 1.0.0^ : Using the default room vs a custom room for user specific communications

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io, socket.io-1.0

socket.io 1.4.5 , node.js 5.x

Forward : A lot of reading, effort, and failure came before this post - so I hope it helps out a lot of future readers.

---

The option of using the default room has confused me when I consider how
to use rooms for user specific communication.(like a direct message)

**Because intuitively, it seems like an out-of-the-box solution that potentially
should deprecate the need of creating a custom room for each user using their 
userID or email like [this popular solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17476294/how-to-send-a-message-to-a-particular-client-with-socket-io/17535099#17535099).**

And since it's created automatically, I figured it should be my one
and only unique listener for each user.

Which lead my due diligence to create this solution:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  var curretUserID = null

  socket.on('set user',function(user){
    userID = curretUserID.id
  });

  io.to(socket.id).emit('welcome','welcome to the room!)

  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){//Makes Sense
    io.emit('chat message', msg);
  });

  socket.on('private message', function(id, msgData){
    if(userID === msg.recipientID){
        socket.to(id).emit('private message', 'for your eyes only');
    }
  });

});
```

I set `userID` to live inside the parent scope `connection` to the avoid need of creating a map between users and sockets because supposedly that is suppose to be the advantage of using the room solution altogether.

Now I haven't seen anyone do it this way, so I have no idea if I'm
completely going a direction unintended with default rooms, or if for
some reason, this doesn't scale or work well in the wild.

Question:

Is this one of the intended uses of the default room, or is creating
a custom room(like in the popular answer mentioned above) still the current way to handle user specific communications?

Answer (score 1):

It's not easy to understand your real problem, especially when you mix up all variables... But I will try to answer your question.

I think the problem hides in socket ids on the server side. Socket.io prepends namespace on each `socket.id`. So let's say your `socket.id` on client side is `4zIISeXsSvKL6VGyAABe`, then on the server side it's `/#4zIISeXsSvKL6VGyAABe`.

I hope socket.io team will fix this issue, because they also created it in recent release.

The way I fix it, I update user.id on client side after connection.

Server:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  socket.emit('register id', socket.id)
}
```

Client:

```
socket.on('register id', function(id){
  socket.id = id
})
```

Then, a private message can be sent like this

Server:

```
io.on('connection', function(
  socket.emit('register id', socket.id)

  io.to(socket.id).emit('welcome','welcome to the room!)

  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){//Makes Sense
    io.emit('chat message', msg);
  });

  socket.on('private message', function(msgData){
        socket.to(msg.recipientID).emit('private message', 'for your eyes only');
  });

});
```

Comment: Please note that since version 1.5.0 (and this [PR](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/pull/2509)), the socket.id on server-side in the default namespace (`/`) will also be `4zIISeXsSvKL6VGyAABe`.