# What is the best way to handle real time chat & messaging system?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, socket.io

I am using `node.js` for backend and `angular` for frontend...

I thought to use `socket.io` but I am not sure how how to handle comunication between users...

For example how can I push message message to specific user after message is saved to database?

ex.

```
router.post('/message', function(req, res) {

    Message.create({
            text: req.body.text,
            fromUser: req.fromToken.id,
            toUser: req.body.toUser   
          }, function(err,message) {
             //FROM HERE WHAT IS THE BEST WAY TO PUSH MESSAGE TO USER  
          })

});
```

Comment: For socket.io, check out the chat room tutorial on their website - http://socket.io/get-started/chat/

Comment: Already checked it, but there is no express routes and they send message to all users not to specific one...

Comment: Could you please be a little more specific in your question, for sending a message to a specific user, there is already an answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17476294/how-to-send-a-message-to-a-particular-client-with-socket-io