# Node and Socket.IO - Private chat (one to one)

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, express, socket.io

I'm creating a chat with Socket.IO and Express to be able to chat one to one (private chat).

**The main problem is:** I want to send a private message to a socket.id, but I want that the sender receives the same message that he sent to the receiver.

```
module.exports = (io, socket) => {
  socket.on('send private message', async (msg) => {
    const emitterUser = // mongoose query to get the emitter
    const receiverUser = // mongoose query to get the receiver

    // sending to individual socketid (private message)
    socket.to(receiverUser.socketId).emit('receiver private message', msg); // <- sending to the receiver
    socket.emit('sender private message', msg);// <- sending to the sender
  });
}
```

I would like to know if is there a better way to do it to create a private chat or if I'm going to the wrong direction.

Comment: I also spent a lot of time before two years on that issue,i think we cant do that with socket.io.We must use some other logic with DB.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65787883/3904109 : have a look here also it might help

Answer (score -1):

You can use the function GROUP of socket-io
docs: https://socket.io/docs/server-api/

**update**

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('people connect: ' + socket.id);

  // listen create and join room from client
  socket.on('create-room', function(nameroom){
    socket.join(nameroom); // if room not exists create and join to room, if room exists client will join to room
    console.log(nameroom);

    // get all name room
    var array=[];
    for(r in socket.adapter.rooms){
      array.push(r);
    }
    console.log(array);
  });

  // listen message from client
  socket.on('client-send-message', function(message){
    io.sockets.in('some-name-room').emit('key-chat', message);
  });
});
```

Comment: Do you mean 'rooms'? I'm trying to figure it out how can I create a room for only 2 users and join them simultaneously. Is it possible to you to demonstrate something about it? Thanks!

Comment: You can create a room and connect two people into one room. Or simply when each connection is made, each socket itself is a room (the main room is the socketId of the same connection). sorry my english is not good

Comment: So.. what is the idea? How can I connect two people in a room simultaneously? That's a thing that I did not find in the docs.