# How to connect the backend to server the frontend to make realtime chatting using socket.io with different users

Tags: javascript, angular, sockets, chat, real-time-updates

I'm using Mongoose to store the chat between different registered users, at the current implementation they can retrieve chat logs if they refresh the page! which is not identical to be a real-time solution. 
How to use socket.io() to act as sender/receiver for many users.

I followed
https://socket.io/get-started/chat/ 
and 
https://medium.freecodecamp.org/simple-chat-application-in-node-js-using-express-mongoose-and-socket-io-ee62d94f5804

But both, they assume the same port for the same user.

Answer (score 0):

It is always a better idea to refer to the official API documentation.

https://socket.io/docs/client-api/

In your case, you need to create a separate socket for a separate private chat

```
//Join PrivateRoom - client
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost');
socket.emit('joinprivate', {email: user1@example.com});

//Server
var io = require('socket.io').listen(80);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.on('joinprivate', function (data) {
    socket.join(data.email); // We are using room of socket io
  });
});
```

More examples:

[How to send a message to a particular client with socket.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17476294/how-to-send-a-message-to-a-particular-client-with-socket-io)