# How do I run an express server listening for MongoDB and listening for socket io messages in Heroku?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, socket.io

I am setting up a server back end for Heroku that is listening for google Oauthentication, listening for messages to save to Mongo DB, and listening for chat messages to send to all connected users using socket io.

Just fyi my application was built using React.

I was able to get these features working as intended when running on my local host, but I had to set up the http server instance used by socket io and the express server used by all other features on two different ports.

However Heroku only gives me access to one port.

I have been looking online for different solutions.

My best bet seems to be trying get sockets io to send messages through the same port, however when I do this, I get an error stating that I can't have two different servers accessing the same port.

So even though I'm using the the same instance of express to create my instance of an http server for socket io, they are considered to be separate instances.

My main issue is, that a http server instance is required for socket io, and every other feature can be run using an express server.

I was wondering if anyone has encountered an issue like this when attempting to deploy to Heroku? I've been looking around for anyone with a similar issue and have not had any luck. I could really use some pointers on this issue.

I am posting my server code below.

Edit 5/21/2019: I decided to cut down to the relevant code, as there was a lot to parse through that was not relevant to the question.

```
require(`dotenv`).config();
require("./config/connection");

const express = require('express');
const app = express();

// Routes to Mongo DB
const chatRouter = require('./routes/chat');

// Passport
const passport = require("passport");
const GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth20').Strategy;
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const keys = require('./config/keys');

// socket io
const server = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);

// google
const routes = require("./routes");
const cookieSession = require('cookie-session');
const path = require('path');

const db = require('./model');

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;

// Tells Express to Read the data sent in JSON format
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());

// Tells Express to allows data to be sent across different origins
// required by CORS policy
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});

// Implementation of other features such as saving chat messages to database
// and implementing passport
...

// Chat implementation using Socket IO

io.on('connection', client => {

  // implementing chat feature
  ...

});

server.listen('8000', () => {
  console.log('listening on port 8000');
});

// alternatively we can attempt to listen on the port specified by Heroku
// server.listen(PORT, () => {
//   console.log(`listening on port ${PORT}`);
// });

// implementing more features, such as Google Oauth
// and other api routes
...

// Express application instance listening on port specified by Heroku
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

I appreciate any help that can be given on this issue.

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Socket.io + NodeJS doesn't work on Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25013735/socket-io-nodejs-doesnt-work-on-heroku)

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like my question was already asked and answered.

You can find the answer at the following link,
[Socket.io + NodeJS doesn't work on Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25013735/socket-io-nodejs-doesnt-work-on-heroku)

I'm just going to give a brief summary here.

Heroku requires our application to run all features of our API on the same port when communicating from the front end to the back end, and vice versa. So My first attempt at specifying two different ports worked locally, but failed when deploying to Heroku.

Then I tried using the same port for both server instances.

```
// implementing express
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

// uses port provided by Heroku OR port 3000
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

...

// implementing Socket IO
const server = require('http').createServer(app); // creates an instance of an http server
const io = require('socket.io')(server);

...

io.on('connection', client => {

    // server side chat features implemented here

}

server.listen(PORT); 

...

app.listen(PORT); // Express is returning a different instance of the http server
```

The solution was simpler than I thought.

Since app.listen(PORT) returns an instance of the http server, we can just use that for Socket IO. I had to look at some example code first before this clicked. One of the teachers in the Full Stack Web Development Bootcamp linked me to this git hub repository demonstrating how to use socket IO when deploying an application to Heroku.

see the following link,
https://github.com/heroku-examples/node-socket.io/blob/master/server.js

The implementation in the example above looks a little different, but is effectively doing the same actions as I will be demonstrating in the example below,

```
// get Express library and create Express application
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

// get socket io library
const SocketIO = require('socket.io');

// uses port provided by Heroku OR port 3000
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

...

// This time we store the HTTP Server instance in a variable
// when we tell the Express application to listen on the specified port
const server = app.listen(PORT); 

// and use that instance to implement our socket io connection
const io = SocketIO.listen(server);

io.on('connection', client => {

    // server side chat features implemented here

}
```

Hopefully this explanation helps others understand and avoid the issue I was facing.

And definitely check out the links posted, as I found them useful for understanding the problem I was facing and how to solve it.