# Socket.io is not connecting on Heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sockets, socket.io

I am using Socket.io in my NodeJS backend. However, the sockets do not work. For example, one should receive a link and then send them to all other rooms under the same code, but the code is not executing. In my heroku logs I receive no errors but when I inspect element the page I get

polling-xhr.js:268 GET https://localhost:5000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NDADDNH net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

and

Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

I have looked into similar problems from this forum and made several changes but none of them have solved the issue. Also a bunch of the posts answer with solutions for ws in general which I don't understand at all :/

From what I read the issue might be with my ports? I followed a few of them but the same errors still occured.

Socket.io:

```
/***BACKEND***/
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();

let rooms = [];

/***SERVER***/
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
server = app.listen(port, function(){
    console.log('App is listening on port ' + port)
});


/***SOCKET.IO***/
const socket = require('socket.io');
io = socket(server);

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
 //bunch of functionality
}
```

and then in my client I am using

```
this.socket = io('localhost:5000');

//one of the functions
        this.syncQueue = () => {
            this.socket.emit('SYNC_QUEUE', {
                activeRoom: this.props.getRoom()
            });
        }

        this.socket.on('RECEIVE_QUEUE', newQueue => {
            props.onAddToQueue(newQueue);
        });
```

FYI Everything works on localhost

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Localhost will not work on the server and if you are using default namespace you no need to specify the URL. So try this, `this.socket = io()`

Comment: This worked great thank you! Such a foolish mistake, I'm ashamed lol

Comment: @ZKJ are your client and server on the same URL?

Comment: @ZKJ Real programmers will always face bugs. :). Good luck.

Comment: @DowenRobinson I believe so, I am not entirely sure how Heroku works I just followed a tutorial to deploy. My file order has the frontend inside the server file.

Answer (score 1):

On the client side, you're trying to connect to localhost:5000 instead of the URL Heroku provides. Try this `this.socket = io('heroku url goes here')`.

Comment: Do I need to change anything server side? I assume I wouldn't be using port 5000 anymore?

Comment: You're already doing that here: `const port = process.env.PORT || 5000`
This is saying if process.env.PORT is not available, use port 5000