# How sent message to a specific ID in Socket.IO 1.3.7

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I want to send message to specific socket. I used below code for this but it's not working and also not getting any error.

```
io.to(socketid).emit("message_to_client",{"message":data.message});
```

Please let me know anything wrong in this.

Any help Appreciated!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647348/send-message-to-specific-client-with-socket-io-and-node-js

Answer (score -1):

You should do this instead because parameter's name aren't string :

```
io.to(socketid).emit("message_to_client",{message : data.message});
```

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp

Comment: A property name can be quoted as a string just fine.  It does not need to be quoted if it has no Javascript reserved characters in it, but with quotes will always work.  This not a solution to the OP's issue.  For your own info, w3schools is not considered a very thorough reference source by many.