# Socket.io client-to-client logic, with lot of users

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I am trying to implement client to client messaging in my app, using `socket.io`, and `node.js` and `Android`.

I searched a little, and found a lot of tutorials, explaining how to deal with targetting specific client when sending messages through `socket.io` socket.

[Send message to specific client with socket.io and node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647348/send-message-to-specific-client-with-socket-io-and-node-js)

The solution is almost always the same : Creating a hashmap object, linking user info such as its `username`, `email address` (or anything unique allowing to identify it), with its `socketid`.
Then calling `io.clients[sessionID].send()`

Now I have two questions :

- This would work if only one instance of the `app` is running, but imagine if my app is divided in multiple instances (for large app). 
  What if a client `A`, connected to instance `X`, wants to send message to user `B`, connected to instance `Z`. If, as seen in the example, `socketids` are stored directly in a simple object existing in the script, some sockets wont know about others users existing in an other instance.
- If I am totally wrong (and I might), is this a good practice to store all user's `socketids` in a single variable ? If yes, would it still be okay with a 50000+ users enviromnment ? If no, should I find another solution like storing user's `socketids` in database ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a redis instance, shared between all your app instances. And you get 2 birds with one stone.

The redis would store all your socket ids in a centralized place.

Comment: Nice, and would you suggest me to keep the object to store socketids ?

Comment: In the redis database. I've modified my answer a bit to clearly reflect this.

Comment: Well no , but that is also part of the solution. In any case, if it's distributed, you'll only work directly with a limited number of socketids per instance (but you'll have access to all of them through the redis instance, for referencing puroposes).  So there shouldn't be any problem in storing all of one instances' ids in a single variable.