# Error in socket creation with socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am a new bee to nodejs, while creating a socket connection I am getting this error response, while I request for a socket connection from client side :

Not Found

404

```
Error: Not Found
    at /home/datacloudserver/nodejs/mychat/app.js:30:13
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/datacloudserver/nodejs/mychat/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/home/datacloudserver/nodejs/mychat/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:312:13)
    at /home/datacloudserver/nodejs/mychat/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:7
    at Function.process_params (/home/datacloudserver/nodejs/mychat/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
    at next (/home/datacloudserver/nodejs/mychat/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
    at /home/datacloudserver/nodejs/mychat/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:618:15
    at next (/home/datacloudserver/nodejs/mychat/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:256:14)
    at Function.handle (/home/datacloudserver/nodejs/mychat/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:176:3)
    at router (/home/datacloudserver/nodejs/mychat/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:46:12)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/datacloudserver/nodejs/mychat/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/home/datacloudserver/nodejs/mychat/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:312:13)
    at /home/datacloudserver/nodejs/mychat/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:7
    at Function.process_params (/home/datacloudserver/nodejs/mychat/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
    at next (/home/datacloudserver/nodejs/mychat/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
    at SendStream.error (/home/datacloudserver/nodejs/mychat/node_modules/serve-static/index.js:121:7)
```

In bin/www file, I have performed some events on connection event:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){ });
```

The node app starts properly,

But when from the client side when I make the call to create socket io object as below :

```
var socket = io(window.CONST.CHATSERVERURL, {secure: true});
```

this call responses the error that I pasted above

Comment: Show us your code what you have tried?

Comment: Hi sahra, does this makes sense ?

Comment: You need to create one js file for server and one for client,which server js file listen for request from client to the specific port that you wish by "socket.emit("message",chatdata) and then run the client code to pull the request to server.for more you can refer to  
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647348/send-message-to-specific-client-with-socket-io-and-node-js] for Lucio Paiva Answer to the question

Comment: Thanks Sahra, it worked :)