# How to notify front-end from backend?

Tags: javascript

I am using multer for file uploading. On the server I have this:

```
stream.on('finish', () => {                                                                              
  console.log('finished')                                                                                
  next()
})
```

What would be the best way (with what command) to notify the frontend that 'finished' has happened? I want to know this in order to have a loading bar.

Comment: That's what websockets are for. The server can send data to the client, and vice-versa. Check out socket.io. Server : `socket.emit("upload finished")`, client : `socket.on("upload finished", function...)`

Comment: That's awesome! Thanks.

Comment: I've added that as an answer, I'd appreciate if you could validate it :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's what websockets are for. The server can send data to the client, and vice-versa. Check out [socket.io](https://socket.io/).

Server : `socket.emit("upload finished")`

Client : `socket.on("upload finished", function...)`

Answer (score 4):

While [Jeremy Thille](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1021703/jeremy-thille) 's answer works well, beware of broadcasting event to all.

`Socket.emit()` simply broadcasts message to all connected clients.

So you need to store the client id of the uploader and notify the progress only to that client and not all.
Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647348/send-message-to-specific-client-with-socket-io-and-node-js).

Comment: You're right, that's all listed in the doc (that's why I gave the link)

Answer (score 2):

You can use sockets for this type of communication. [socket.io](https://socket.io/) is a node package for web sockets. In the server you have

`socket.emit('done')`

whereas in the client side you can attach to the emit to receive new data

```
socket.on('done', function (data) {
    // Do something with data
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, I know I am 5 years 7 months late but still I want to share my opinion.
Socket is a really good approach but another way can also be SSE(Server Sent Events) to automatically notify the frontend via HTTP but you can notify the frontend using only text message .

**For FrontEnd:**

1. First you have to create eventsource object.

```
let sse = new EventSource(
       "URL for backend",
        { withCredentials: true }
      )
```

here credential is for the cookie to pass.

2.Now add eventListeners to get the result from backend.

```
see.onmessage = (e)=>{
let data = JSON.parse(e.data)
//now do whatever you want with the data
}
```

**For Backend:**

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");
const app = express();
const PORT = 5000;
let clients = [];

const event = (req, res) => {
 
  const headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'text/event-stream',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
  }
  
  res.writeHead(200, headers)
  let message = { event_name: 'ONGOING' }

  const data = `data: ${JSON.stringify(facts)}\n\n`

  res.write(data)
  const clientId = Date.now()

  const newClient: Client = {
    id: clientId,
    response: res,
  }

  clients.push(newClient)

  req.on('close', () => {
    console.log(`${clientId} Connection closed`)
    clients = clients.filter((clients: Client) => clients.id !== clientId)
  })
};
const notifyEvent = ()=>{
 let newMessage = { event_name: 'FINISHED' }

  const data = `data: ${JSON.stringify(newMessage)}\n\n`
  
  // Send a message to each client
  clients.forEach((client) => client.response.write(data))
}
//Here goes your part
stream.on('finish', () => {                                                                              
  console.log('finished')
  return notifyEvent()                                                                         
  next()
})
app.get("/event", event);

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`App listening on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

So this is basically the whole thing.
I am attaching a link which helped me to understand the SSE.
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/nodejs-server-sent-events-build-realtime-app