# How to send message to specific user in socket.io?

Tags: node.js

I am creating a chat application in Socket.io and node I am new in this I have a some query regarding chat app how can we maintain user's list and how can we send a message to specific person from user list?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send message to specific client with socket.io and node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647348/send-message-to-specific-client-with-socket-io-and-node-js)

Comment: i didn't find any appropriate answer that's why i am asking you can help me ?

Comment: [Then check the cheat sheet.](https://socket.io/docs/emit-cheatsheet) Not sure what you consider an *appropriate answer*.

Comment: i checked but how can i get user socket.id ?

Comment: You really should read documentation before jumping to development.

Comment: i read but didn't find appropriate solution so if you have any fast solution then please tell it's urgent

Answer (score 1):

Like this (On the server-side) [Cheatsheet](https://socket.io/docs/emit-cheatsheet/):

```
  // sending to individual socketid (private message)
  socket.to(<socketid>).emit('hey', 'I just met you');
```

The `<>` chatacters can be omitted, just make sure you replace `socketid` with whatever the socket ID truly is. This will sent a message to ONLY the socket id specified. I know this works because I use it.

Comment: Thanks for help but how can i get socket id because when user refresh page then socket id will be change

Comment: If the user refreshes the page then the socket connection disconnects, and when they connect again they get a NEW socket id. You either need to prevent page refreshing if you are dealing with a form, or use some sort of unique identifier on the back-end that stores a user's info for when they reconnect again. If this is a chat app, I recommend AJAX.