# Using the socket id as a userId to send a certain user a message in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, socket.io

In need to know, how "user a" can send "user b" a message using socketIo in nodejs.

Reading the documentation of socketIo, there is a clear explanation of not using the id of an socket as an userid, because after every reconnection the socketid is regenerated.

[SocketIo Documentation](https://socket.io/docs/v4/server-socket-instance/)

But reading this article on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647348/send-message-to-specific-client-with-socket-io-and-node-js) and other tutorials telling me the opposite.

So what is the correct way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In a messaging application you should probably store your roomID (you can create an unique uid which can act as a room and connect the users using the roomId) in a database so that both the users get connected to a specific room and send/receive messages.